# Build an HTML ID by concatenating several previous numbered paragraphs

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I created an XML workflow that allows the user to create HTML output with a rich hypertext scheme that builds the anchors and hyperlinks using an XSL. But I am having trouble creating an anchor for the second and third level of specific subsections of the text using the numbering in the parent elements.

The main sections have a number such as 14, the subsections use the number and number with a dash, such 14-1, 14-2. The next level uses a letter such as a, b, c. The next level uses a roman numeral, such as i, ii, iii etc.

So the anchor should reference each of the previous parents, such as 14-2ci or 14-3cii.

Here is a sample of the XML (sorry for the formatting, I couldn't get the code to display properly by indenting four spaces):

`<Root><RULE>`

`<rule_subhead><num_sub>14-3</num_sub>. Artificial Devices, Unusual Equipment and Unusual Use of Equipment </rule_subhead>`

`<rule_letter><strong><num>a</num>.</strong> That might assist him in making a <em>stroke</em> or in his play; or </rule_letter>`

`<rule_letter><strong><num>b</num>.</strong> For the purpose of gauging or measuring distance or conditions that might affect his play; or </rule_letter>`

`<rule_letter><strong><num>c</num>.</strong> That might assist him in making a <em>stroke</em> or in his play; or </rule_letter>`

`<rule_letter_sub>(<num>i</num>) gloves may be worn provided that they are plain gloves; </rule_letter_sub>`

`<rule_letter_sub>(<num>ii</num>) resin, powder and drying or moisturizing agents may be used; and </rule_letter_sub>`

`<rule_letter_sub>(<num>iii</num>) a towel or handkerchief 
   may be wrapped around the grip. </rule_letter_sub>`
`</RULE>
     </Root>`

The numbers are all tagged with the `<num>` tag. Is there a way to concatenate all the numbers from the previous elements if they are not nested parents?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the XSLT you've already got?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *preceding* axis to look for the last 'parent' section, note that you need to specify the '`position() = 1`' to ensure you get the nearest precending node.

It's not clear quite what output you're after, but in these templates the $anc variable in each case has the value you're after e.g. '14-3ciii'.

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rule_subhead/num_sub">
    <xsl:variable name="anc"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:variable>
    <a name="{$anc}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></a>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rule_letter//num">
    <xsl:variable name="anc">
        <xsl:value-of select="preceding::rule_subhead[position() = 1]/num_sub" />
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:variable>
    <a name="{$anc}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></a>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rule_letter_sub/num">
    <xsl:variable name="anc">
        <xsl:value-of select="preceding::rule_subhead[position() = 1]/num_sub" />
        <xsl:value-of select="preceding::rule_letter[position() = 1]//num" />
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:variable>
    <a name="{$anc}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></a>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to create an HTML anchor using the numbering from the following XML code: 

   <rule_subhead><num_sub>14-3</num_sub>...</rule_subhead>
   <rule_letter><strong><num>a</num>.</strong>...</rule_letter>
   <rule_letter><strong><num>b</num>.</strong>...</rule_letter> 
   <rule_letter><strong><num>c</num>.</strong>...</rule_letter>
     <rule_letter_sub>(<num>i</num>)...</rule_letter_sub> 

...so that the attribute for the "i" element appears as:
<p id="r14-3c-i">...</p>

Comment: @jim-maivald A paragraph tag such as <p id="r14-3c-i">...</p> isn't an anchor - which are you after? More to the point, can you provide an example of the actual output you want from it?